# How to send fcm token using url parameter?

Tags: android, android-webview, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have generated the fcm token and stored the token in Sharedpref and now I want the token to be sent to [this API](https://example.com/auth/saveToken)

```
{username:"" , fcmToken:""}
```

So how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using retrofit as easy as :

```
@Post("auth/saveToken")
Call<...> listRepos(@Path("username") String user, @Path("fcmToken" String token));
```

http://square.github.io/retrofit/